# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to parse JSON with JSON simple

Tags: java, json, classnotfoundexception, json-simple

I use JSON simple to parse JSON and I get `NoClassDefFoundError` when trying to create `JSONParser` object.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
...
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
```

I compile program with command:

```
javac MyProgram.java -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar
```

And it compiles fine.
But when I execute program with this command:

```
java MyProgram
```

I get `NoClassDefFoundError`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:
Full error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser
        at getNotesFromNoter.sendPost(getNotesFromNoter.java:53)
        at getNotesFromNoter.main(getNotesFromNoter.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

Comment: you are missing the jar in your classpath. Try using an IDE like Eclipse, configure the build path and run it inside it

Answer (score 6):

You're not including the Simple JSON jar file in your classpath when running. You want:

```
// Unix
java -cp .:json-simple-1.1.1.jar MyProgram

// Windows
java -cp .;json-simple-1.1.1.jar MyProgram
```

(The `:` or `;` is the path separator for the relevant operating system.)

When you compile Java and specify a classpath, that's just telling the compiler about the classes to compile *against* - it doesn't include the library in the *result* of the compilation, so you still need to specify the classpath in order to run the code, too.

Comment: I tried to run code with classpath but I still get the same error

Comment: @SPython: Well you've not told us the full error, which makes it harder to help you. Maybe there are more jar files you need. Please edit your question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an IDE, download the jar from [this link](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/list).In netbeans and eclipse you can add this jar by right clicking on project then selecting properties->libraries->Add jar->Select the jar and click ok.

Answer (score 1):

Did you compile your code with -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar?

Sometime ago, I made a Test.java, and compiled with:

```
javac -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar Test.java
```

Then:

```
java -cp .:json-simple-1.1.1.jar Test
```

And It ran perfectly.